# How to test different resolutions using sf::viewport on SFML, c++

Tags: c++, sfml, resolution, scaling

I am trying to test scaling resolution in SFML.

```
sf::RenderWindow window;
window.create(sf::VideoMode(1680, 1050, 32), "test", 
sf::Style::Fullscreen);

sf::View view(sf::FloatRect(0, 0, 1600, 900));
sf::FloatRect port;
port = sf::FloatRect( 0.1428 / 2, 0, 1 - (0.1428), 1);
view.setViewport(port);
```

0.1428 is, when I resize 1050 to 900, I need to put black bars to reduce horizontal pixels 14.28% so I can keep the aspect ratio same.

so , to keep aspect ratio same, new shown resolution will be 1440,900 and 240 px(which is 14.28% of 1680) as blackbars.

my original screen resolution is 1920x1080, but to check this test , I've changed it to 1680,1050.

here is the result : https://prnt.sc/m9uuc9

circle is still not a perfect circle. it looks scaled unequally.

what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the default constructor of videomode, and still using fullscreen. This is what we used for our project and it works.